# What is the relation between the square of a function's derivative and its sup norm?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a continuously differentiable function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $f(0)$. How can we prove the square of the sup norm of the function is not larger than the integral of the square of the derivative of the function from $0$ to $1$?

I first tried with functions like $x^n$ but have no ideas how to prove the general case.
[image]

Comment: What is with $f(0)$?

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
|f(x)|&=|f(x)-f(0)|\\
&=\left|\int_{0}^{x}f'(t)dt\right|\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{x}|f'(t)|dt\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{1}|f'(t)|dt\\
&\leq\left(\int_{0}^{1}f'(t)^{2}dt\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{0}^{1}1^{2}dt\right)^{1/2}\\
&=\left(\int_{0}^{1}f'(t)^{2}dt\right)^{1/2},
\end{align*}
the rest is easy.

Comment: The fifth line is Cauchy-Schwarz PS: You were faster than me :D

Comment: Thank you so much!